# Rails "destroy" method doesn't work after where quoery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods

Hello I have this function in my controller

```
  def destroy
    fallower = Fallower.where(user_id: 1, author_id: 2).first
    fallower.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

it throws me this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in FallowersController#destroy

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "fallowers" WHERE "fallowers"."" = $
```

**fallower model**

```
class Fallower < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**fallowers table**

```
class CreateFallowers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :fallowers, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.integer :author_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

any idea why normal destroy function doens't work this time?

Comment: Can you post your `Fallower` model with associations? And also debug `fallower` variable and post the result.

Comment: Seems like you don't have id column present. try use delete_all instead

Comment: yea I don't have id column in the table.

Comment: Why don't you have an `id` column? Add it and everything will work fine.

Comment: Or change the primary key: self.primary_key = '[fieldyouwant]' (in the model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to destroy record because their is no ID column in your schema and `destroy` method work on ID(primary key by default) column.

You can solve this issue in two ways :

1) You can add any other primary key in your table schema and set this in your model as below. But this option will not affect your previously added records.

```
class Fallower < ActiveRecord::Base
  primary_key :xxx_id
  belongs_to :user
end
```

2) You can call `delete_all` method with condition, Because it not initialize object first. More detail [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class).

```
def destroy
  Fallower.delete_all(user_id: 1, author_id: 2)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```